# unable to train in batches on TensorflowJS

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, neural-network, classification, tensorflow.js

I am trying out an Iris data classifier (a total of 150 elements) using tensorflow JS.

xTrain and yTrain are both an array of tensors and I am using batches of 10 (batchx, batchy)

```
for(var i=0; i<epochs; i++){
    while(end of one epoch){
        var batchx = xTrain;
        var batchy = yTrain;
        batchx.slice(c,c+batch_size);
        batchy.slice(c,c+batch_size);
        const history = model.fit(batchx, batchy,{
            batchSize: batch_size, epochs: 1
        });
        c = c+1;
    }
}
```

But the console throws an error:
[image]

One of the layers in my model is defined like so.

```
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    units: 10,
    activation: 'sigmoid',
    inputShape: [4],
    name: 'hidden_layer',
}));
```

I am guessing that the error is because the input shape has to be a single tensor of 4 elements. How can I tell it to take batches of tensors? Or is there a better method for training?

EDIT: xTrain for example had

```
e {isDisposed: false, size: 600, shape: Array(2), dtype: "float32", strides: Array(1), …}
```

Comment: Could you provide the value of xTrain and yTrain

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel I have made the edits

Comment: Could you give us the code where model is defined? Because I don't know if the layer you showed is the first